# convert a list of characters to a list of ascii value

Tags: python

Is there a build in method to transform a list of characters to a list of ascii values of those characters?

For example, The method should transform `['a','b','c']` to `[ord('a'),ord('b'),ord('c')]`.

Comment: For completeness sake, no. There is no built-in, however, you can create the behavior easily by combining a few existing built-in utilities. i.e. See the answer @AlexandrShurigin provides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think that Python has a build in method, but that's pretty easy to write a "one-liner".

```
source = ['a', 'b', 'c']

print([ord(c) for c in source])
```

outputs

```
[97, 98, 99]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to call the ord function on all of the entries.

```
result = list(map(ord, ['a','b','c']))
print(results)
```

Comment: You just printed a `map` instance, which is like the handle of a generator or iterator. You would need to consume that into a list or other container for this to work. `list(map(ord, ['a','b','c']))`

Comment: @flakes thanks! Not too familiar with python, just googled "python map array". Feels like it's cleaner than the other responses.

Comment: @ExpDev A list comprehension is probably even cleaner, it’s certainly more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have python 3 you can do this with the bytes function:

```
list(bytes(''.join(['a','b','c']).encode()))

# [97, 98, 99]
```